# Python: why do I get an error when I try to import geopands?

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying to impor `geopandas` but I get the following error

```
import geopandas as gpd

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-05b2e8edd391> in <module>()
     21 import seaborn as sns
     22 #from osgeo import gdal
---> 23 import geopandas as gpd
     24 #import fiona
     25 from scipy.stats import skew

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries
      2 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame
----> 3 from geopandas.geodataframe import points_from_xy
      4 
      5 from geopandas.io.file import read_file

ImportError: cannot import name 'points_from_xy'
```

Comment: How did you install geopandas?

Answer (score 1):

That function [is rather new](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/commit/39e724b475c57b11d4de0afac6d4bf2814ef209b#diff-aafd711e1343695485f152fc920ac36a) and only available in the Github repository right now. The recent release 0.4.1 [does not include it](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/5f60528d76b6c27b587a7ad7404f4c60848e4466/geopandas/geodataframe.py).